# Identify this PCB connector

Tags: connector, identification, header

Do you know this connector? I tried in vain for hours using a variety of search terms.

Pitch is 2.54 mm and width of arc-bent contact is 1.4 mm. I just wish to find a part number, manufacturer and/or a different connector that is very similar to this.

[image: 2.54mm pitch connector]

**EDIT 1**

[image]

Comment: SMD of the same connector above would suffice, too. The arc-bent part on top is what I need.

Comment: Oh! I didn't understand, I thought the bent part was the leads you'd solder.to a board; my suggestion wouldn't work.

Comment: It would be helpful if you would state how it is used.  What connects to the bent parts?  To their lower or upper surface?  Are you trying to repair something such that alternatives might work, or are you trying to source this for new production?

Comment: @ChrisStratton Added. Dimensions aren't that important as I'm looking for something similar. It's for a prototype initially. Mass production is too far off to prepare for it right now.

Comment: When you say "card", is that a PCB with a hole on its side or like stacked PCBs?

Comment: What's wrong with a right angle card edge connector?

Comment: @gustavovelascoh Yes, that correct.

Comment: @ChrisStratton RA is fine, too. I just need a mating connector that is able to fit snug inside the card shown in my illustration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That looks to me like one of these oldschool LCD panel connectors. One would use two and slot the LCD glass inbetween:

The connectors:

[image: connectors]

Type of LCDs used with those:

[image: an LCD used with said connectors]

I haven't looked anywhere as to where can one source them for any serious production runs; but I hope this might point you in the right direction.

Source:

- [A czech surplus shop selling some of the connectors](https://www.hadex.cz/k316b-patice-k-displeji-4dr822-a-4dt822---par-2rk49720/)
- [Same shop, the LCD.](https://www.hadex.cz/k316g-displej-4dt821a---pruhledny-bez-reflexni-vrstvy/)

I am in no way affiliated with said shop; I just once found those on there.

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I was looking for.
Thanks for your research.

Comment: Nice one! I read almost the whole catalogue from Molex, Amphenol and Hirose and did not find any similar connector.

Answer (score 2):

Similar, but different. Surface mount compression contacts. https://www.digikey.com/short/j02v3j
[image]

Comment: Thanks. It helps, but it isn't a solution for me right now.
I'll keep looking for the origin of the original part I'm looking for, though.